# LibGDX: Collision only works with one Rectangle

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

In my android game the collision works as long as I only have one rectangle in my Array, so it works with this:

```
rects = new Rectangle[1];
 for(int i = 0; i < rects.length; ++i)
  rects[i] = new Rectangle(i * 150, 0, 150, 150);
```

but not if I add another rectangle `rects = new Rectangle[2];`

My collision code looks like this:

```
public boolean collision(Rectangle rect){
 return (Intersector.overlaps(playerBound, rect));
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rects.length; ++i){
 if(!collision(rects[i]))
  player.setY(player.getY() - 1f);
}
```

playerBound is initialized like this: `playerBound = new Rectangle(player.getX(), player.getY(), player.getWidth(), player.getHeight() + 1);`

What is the problem? I don't understand how it can work if there's only one rectangle in the array but not if there's more.

Comment: Are you sure the second new rectangle is in between braces, always use braces to contain functionality in loops or if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's because there is a logical error in this code snippet here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rects.length; ++i){
    if(!collision(rects[i]))
        player.setY(player.getY() - 1f);
}
```

You check more than one rectangle for collision. Let's assume that the first one in the array **will** cause a collision. Fine, the Y won't change. Now there is another rect. This second rect will **not** cause a collision. What happens now? You change the player's Y value even though there has been a collision.

Change it to something like this:

```
boolean collision = false;
for(int i = 0; i < rects.length; ++i){
    if(collision(rects[i]))
        collision = true;
}

if (collision == false)
    player.setY(player.getY() - 1f);
```